# Inheritance super variables

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, super

I'm writing a simple program in which I have a super class `Person` inherited by the sub-classes `Customer` and `Employee` (they inherit the variables `ID`, `name` and `surname`).

```
public class Person {

    int id;
    String name;
    String surname;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(int i, String n, String s) {
        id = i;
        name = n;
        surname = s;
    }
}
```

```
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {

    String username;
    String password;
    String date;
    int hpw;
    int recordSold;
    float hourPay;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String u, String n, String s, String p, int i, int h, String d, int rSold, float hPay) {
        username = u;
        super.name = n;
        super.surname = s;
        password = p;
        super.id = i;
        hpw = h;
        date = d;
        recordSold = rSold;
        hourPay = hPay;
    }
}
```

However the problem is here: when I try to get the variables `ID`, `name` and `surname` through my main class, they fail to return (0,null,null). Why is this? I have get-Methods in my sub-classes which should return the super variables, but they are not. Thanks for your time and patience.

```
public String getName() {
    return super.name;
}
```

---

UPDATE:
ok so I sorted out the super(id,name,surname) in the Employee class constructor. I also removed all the getters and setters in the employee class since those are inherited from the Person superclass (correct me if I'm wrong?..)

Person superclass:

```
public class Person {
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;

public Person () {
}

public Person(int i, String n, String s) {
    this.id = i;
    this.name = n;
    this.surname = s;
}

public void setID(int i) {
    this.id = i;
}
public void setName(String n) {
    this.name = n;
}
public void setSurname(String s) {
    this.surname = s;
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
```

}

Employee subclass:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {

protected String username;
protected String password;
protected String date;  
protected int hpw;
protected int recordSold;
protected float hourPay;

public Employee() {
    super();
}

public Employee(int i, String u, String n, String s, String p, int h, String d, int r, float hP) {
    super(i,n,s);
    username = u;
    password = p;
    date = d;
    hpw = h;
    recordSold = r;
    hourPay = hP;
}

public void setUser(String u) {
    username = u;
}

public void setPassword(String p) {
    password = p;
}

public void setHWeek (int h) {
    hpw = h;
}

public void setDate (String d) {
    date = d;
}

public void setRSold (int r) {
    recordSold = r;
}

public void setHPay (float p) {
    hourPay = p;
}

public String getUser() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public int getHWeek() {
    return hpw;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public int getRSold() {
    return recordSold;
}

public float getHPay() {
    return hourPay;
}
```

however, when I run the main program the ID, name and surname variables are still null, they are not being returned by the superclass. Am I missing something please? Thanks

Comment: Please show how you are instantiating the `Employee` object

Comment: Can you please provide an runable Program that shows the problem?

Comment: What @Jens said, the problem is not in this code

Comment: @TheLostMind He is definetly in Employee(), Java calls the default super constructor for him. However it should still work

Comment: @LionC - We will *only* get to know if he shows us his *instantiating* code.

Comment: @TheLostMind given the classes above, there is no way to instantiate Employee without calling the default constructor Peron()

Comment: You should learn to do it right from the start, it will make your life easier in the future.   
Google "Java design principles"  

Your class properties/variables should be private.  
You class constructor should call the superclass constructor as first statement and pass any superclass stored values to it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat 
It does actually answer the question - bad design is a cause of may hard to detect problems, try to connect your electric wires incorrectly somewhere in you (big) installation and then try to work out why the whole installation does not work in the way you expect it to work.  The code as it is bad but it will work, it does **not** work because the OP forgot to post something else.

Comment: General principal - the class that contains the properties/variables should contain the (public?) accessors and modifiers. (if not private) They will be inherited by subclasses.

Comment: @GermannArlington `it does not work because the OP forgot to post something else` - hence my original comment

Comment: @ScaryWombat From what OP posted so far it is clear that there are too many problems in the "installation" to try fixing just "this one little light (that does not work)" - it requires complete "rewiring".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance only works for methods **NOT** for variables. It is also bad practice to implement methods in subclasses that access super class variables directly. You'd better implement access methods in your superclass. Due to inheritance, those methods will be available in the sub-classes ass well.

Another thing is the visibility of you instance varibles. You are using the default visibility which is "package-wide". So if your sub-classes are not in the same package, they can't access those variables. If you use "private" or "protected" visibility you are much safer accessing the variables.

Another point is that you are initializing the objects not correctly. Calling the sub-class constructor has to call the super-class constructor as well because your Employee object relies on the functionality that your Person object provides. A more scientific description of this principle exists:

> Barbara Liskov - Liskov substitution principle

```
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(int i, String n, String s) {
        id = i;
        name = n;
        surname = s;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }
}
```

Add access methods for super class instance variables and set visibility to private.

```
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String date;
    private int hpw;
    private int recordSold;
    private float hourPay;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String u, String n, String s, String p, int i, int h, String d, int rSold, float hPay) {
        super(id, name, surname);
        this.username = u;
        this.password = p;
        this.hpw = h;
        this.date = d;
        this.recordSold = rSold;
        this.hourPay = hPay;
    }
}
```

Call the super class constructor for initialization of the super class.

Comment: Yes using default super constructors is not good style. Yes OP should change this. No this is not the cause of the problem, OP's Employee(String, String...)-constructor works the way he wants it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "Inheritance only works for methods NOT for variables"? You can obviously use variables from super-class in sub-class

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class Person {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String surname;

  public Person (int id, String name, String surname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  ... //similarly for getName() and getSurname()
}


public class Employee extends Person {

  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String date; 
  private int hpw;
  private int recordSold;
  private float hourPay;

  public Employee (int id, String name, String surname, String username, String password, String date, int hpw, int recordSold, float hourPay) {
    super(id, name, surname);

    this.username = username;
    ... //similarly for other parameters.
  }
 }
```

The important bit is `super(id, name, surname)`.

#### EDIT

[lionc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319378/lionc) claims that I did not answer the question, which is true. I did this because [the original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149152/user3149152) seems to be new to Java and, hence, might be asking the "wrong" question. I should have highlighted this in my original response. Given that my answer is currently marked as the best, I believe that I made the right decision.

Comment: While you are right that this would be better style, the way OP is doing it is technically correct

Comment: @LionC it is technically correct to use blue wire as a live conductor in your electrical installation - the colour of the wire does **not** change the wire's properties, but anybody who will have to use/maintain your installation will **not** be thankful when they discover it and you will **not** be happy about it 10 years later either.

Comment: @GermannArlington That is 100% correct, but that is not the point of the question and thus should not be the only content of an answer, as the problem OP is asking about lies in the code that instantiates the Objects and not in the code he posted. But people answer him, saying that the code he posted is wrong,t hat he should do it different and that this would fix the problem, while that it just not true.

Comment: Sorry if I did not ask the proper question and/or in the proper way. I'm actually very new to these forums and trying my best to be direct to the point and clear. I appreciate all your time and patience, thanks.

Comment: @Logan, no problem! Asking the "right" question is very difficult. Especially when there are underlying problems which prevent you from getting to the core of the problem.

I didn't explain the usage of `this` and your usage is poor form. The `this` operator enables you to distinguish between a variable provided as input to a function and a variable in the class. Hence, I can write `f(int i) { this.i = i; }`, rather than `f(int ii) { i = ii; }` (i.e., class variables and function variables can have the same name). It is bad style to write `f(int i) { this.j = i; }` (as you have done).

Comment: @Logan, I'm new to Stack Overflow too, but I suspect that your problems are better suited to a java forum.

Comment: @Logan, one of the answers proposes `public int getId() { return this.id; }`, there is no need for the `this.` in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

You define those attributes in both of your classes so you override them in the subclass. Moreover, your Employee constructor is not the way it should. You should call the adapted super-constructor as your first statement.

```
public class Person {

    protected int       id;
    protected String    name;
    protected String    surname;

    public Person(int id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id      = id;
        this.name    = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}

public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {
    private String  username;
    private String  password;
    private String  date;
    private int     hpw;
    private int     recordSold;
    private float   hourPay;

    public Employee(String username, String name, String surname, String pswd, int id,
            int hpw, String date, int rSold, float hPay) {
        super(id,name,surname);
        this.username   = username;
        this.password   = pswd;
        this.hpw        = hpw;
        this.date       = date;
        this.recordSold = rSold;
        this.hourPay    = hPay;
    }
}
```

In your constructors, I consider a best practice to give the same name to your parameters as the name of your attributes to initialize and differenciate them thanks to `this`. Some people also use the same names except that they add a `_` at the beginning of all the members of the class. In any case, don't use such meaningless names as "s", "n" etc when the variables they represent have a special meaning (surname, name). Keep those names for example for local variables without any particular semantic (n would be an integer, s would be a String...).

Comment: First, please write complete answers, do not post answers that even contain the statement that theyre not complete and that you will make them complete soon. Second, as already mentioned in other answers, yes this would be better style but it is not the technical problem, as implicitly calling default constructors and setting super.fields works

Comment: I also removed the default constructors which are not recommended in most cases (even if they are sometimes required for example for JPA). The use of default constructors the way he does it is actually the most probable cause of his problem. This is not only a style answer.

Comment: But it is not the problem. The code OP posted works.

Comment: His attributes are not initialized... meaning ? He called the default constructor.

Comment: He definetly calls the default constructor of Person (well, Java does it for him). But he is setting the fields himself in the Employee-constructor, which should work. So using the Person() default constructor is not the Problem. Just c&p OP's code into an IDE and test it yourself, it works

Answer (score -1):

You haven't initialized those variables, that's why it is returning default value for those variables. In java following are default values for variables.

```
int -> 0
String -> null (because  String is Object in Java)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you don't need tu use `super` to access the attributes defined in the super class since you are using package visibility for them (and both seems to be in the same package).

However, this is NOT the proper way to write Java code.

You should define a visibility for your attributes. In most case, it is recommended to use `private` visibility and to define getter and setter methods to access them:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(int id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // And so on...
}
```

In sub-classes, you just have to call `getId()` or `setId(...)` to access the Id attribute. No need to call `super.getId()`. Since `Employee` extends `Person`, it has access to all of its public, protected (and package if they are in the same package) attributes and method.

This means that in your current code, you can simply write `name = n` instead of `super.name = n`.

```
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String date;
    private int hpw;
    private int recordSold;
    private float hourPay;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String username, String name, String surname, String password, int id, int hpw, String date, int rSold, float hPay) {
        super(id, name, surname);
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.hpw = hpw;
        this.date = date;
        this.recordSold = rSold;
        this.hourPay = hPay;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    // And so on...
}
```

Now to use these classes, you can write code like:

```
Employee e = new Employee("user3149152", "Ulrich", "Ser", "passwd", 1234, 0, "2014/08/13", 0, 0);
System.out.println("Employee " + e.getName() + ' ' + e.getSurname() + " has for id " + e.getId() + '.');
```

For reference, this code works even with your current code.
It prints:

```
Employee Ulrich Ser has for id 1234.
```

Comment: This would be better style, but the way OP is doing it (implicitly calling default super constructos and setting super.fields) works technically, so this is not really an answer to the question

Comment: I think writing proper code is the best way to start learning a language.

Comment: Nobody will disagree with you on this one, however this is not the point of the question

Comment: Not sure he is looking for a technical answer.